# Parsing a settingsfile in bashscript where some special settings are arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, scripting, ifs

I am still quite new to bash scripting and I am somehow stuck.
I am looking for a clean and easy way to parse a settingsfile, where some special (and known) settings are arrays.

So the settings file looks like this.

```
foo=(1 2 3 4)
bar="foobar"
```

The best solution I came up with so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash    
while IFS== read -r k v; do
    if [ "$k" = "foo" ]
        then
          IFS=' ' read -r -a $k <<< "$v"
        else
          declare "$k"="$(echo $v | tr -d '""')"
        fi
    done < settings.txt
```

But I am obviously mixing up array types. As far is I understood and tried out for the `bar="foobar"` part this actually declares an array, and could be accessed by `echo ${bar[0]}` but as well as `echo $bar`. So I thought this would be a indexed array, but the error log clearly states something different:

> cannot convert associative to indexed array

Would be glad if somebody could explain me a little bit how to find a proper solution.

Comment: `tr -d '""'` just `tr -d '"'`. So did you debug your script with `set -x` to see what is happenning? `As far is I understood and tried out for the bar="foobar" part this actually declares an array, and could be accessed by echo ${bar[0]} but as well as echo $bar` No, you understood wrongly. [I can't reproduce your error](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/EcstaticImaginarySupercollider#main.sh). Most probably you have some `declare -a foo` leftover.

Comment: I just realised my error, don't know how I managed that but had `read -r -A` in my script which didn't work. Sorry thats was my fault. But in my shell version (4.2.46(2)-release) `$bar` and `$bar[0]` really outputs **foobar** while `$bar[1]` has no output, what I still not really get because you said I am wrong there

Comment: It's just defined like that - using array expansion with non-array variables acts as-if the array has one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it safe for you to just source the file?

```
. settings.txt
```

That will insert all the lines of the file as if they were lines of your current script. Obviously, there are security concerns if the file isn't as secure as the script file itself.

Comment: This would actually be fine for the moment because it is still an internal project, but won't be enough  in the near future. And I would really like to understand what the underlying misassumption is.

Comment: `won't be enough in the near future` Why? It's universal, easy to implement, well documented, etc... It allows users of your program to pass (create/fetch/even download from remote location) any configuration with ease. There are many projects that use such way of specifying configuration.

Comment: In a nutshell, not because of security concerns, the read function in a while loop is most suitable for me because the script will have extended functionality in every iteration.

Comment: I think you are overthinking this. Perhaps better to just simplify your design if possible.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this is a very special and rare use case, where the main goal is to provide a workflow, which is as fault tolerant as possible without a GUI

Comment: doesn't change the fact that I'd design it for sourcing the file if possible.